# Can AWS API Gateway send requests to an Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

Does anybody know if it is possible to use AWS API Gateway together with Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment and how to configure it?

I would like to make at post request with json content through AWS API Gateway to a Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment, which makes some business calculation (duration about 1-2 sec.) and send the response back.

I hope somebody can give me some input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, EB worker environment does not work like a regular HTTP API. Instead of a HTTP endpoint where you can post your JSON content and get the results from its processing as a response, it **exposes an SQS queue**.

Thus, in your use case, the API gateway would have to be **integrated with the SQS queue**. Such integration is described for example here:

- [Creating an AWS Service Proxy for Amazon SQS](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-aws-service-proxy-for-amazon-sqs)

However, the results of the processing **won't be returned to you**. Instead SQS queue will return 200 code that it got the message. So you as a client, will just get a confirmation that the json payload was submitted to the SQS queue, not that it the json payload was processed by the worker.

The reason is that the worker environment processes these messages asynchronously. The worker environment would have to store the results of the processing somewhere (e.g. DynamoDb) and you would have to have a **mechanism to query for the results**. For example, a second API call to check if your message has been already processed based on some unique `message_id`.

Comment: Hi Marcin, Thanks for your reply. Should I then choose another solution like AWS API Gateway -> EC instance or ... and  what about load balancing etc.?

Comment: Could I use Elastic Beanstalk Web Server Environment for this?